# How play music from NSString

Tags: json, uitableview, uibutton, nsarray, avplayer

I make parse from `JSON`. `NSString "song"` in `JSON` have many tracks. So I need these tracks to play. I also created a button for music in `tableviewcell`. But when I pushed on my button player play only last track in the list in my `NSString`. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *person in json) {

    NSString *name = [person objectForKey:@"performer"];

    NSString *name2 = [person objectForKey:@"sound"];

    NSLog(@"%@", name2);

    NSURL *urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:name2];

    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:urlStream];
```

I used also play and stop player in my button. I used `AVPlayer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you init your player over again with each song, so it doesn't keep the previous ones.
Try using different AVPlayers (init an array of players) or just load the first one and load the next from the array when it's finished.

Hope this is helpful.